# If a gyroscope is provided a torque in space, what will its motion be after the torque ceases to act?

Tags: angular-momentum, torque, space, gyroscopes, precession

As there will be no energy dissipation, where will the kinetic energy of precession go as the gyroscope can't precess in the absence of a torque?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Re *As there will be no energy dissipation* -- That's a mighty big assumption. Real gyroscopes have bearings that aren't perfect.

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/389166/can-precession-happen-with-no-external-forces/389452#389452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before discussing this question, let me recommend the following article to read: '[It has to go down in order to go around](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.5288)'. It is very relevant for your question.

Svilen Kostov and Daniel Hammer have verified experimentally that as part of the process of starting gyroscopic precession the gyroscope wheel always yields a little to the torque that is exerted. The faster the spin rate of the gyroscope wheel the smaller the displacement. In the far majority of demonstrations the spin rate of the gyroscope wheel is so large that the motion of yielding to the torque is not perceptible with the naked eye. (This explains why this yielding is not generally known.)

So yes, I do confirm that at the moment that you start exerting a torque on the gyroscope wheel some work is done.

In the absence of any dissipation of energy you end up with a persistent nutation.

As a thought experiment a case without dissipation is certainly possible. You can construct a gyroscope wheel that is magnetized in such a way that its magnetic field is aligned with its spin axis. You put that gyroscope wheel in orbit. By applying an external magnetic field you can exert a torque. In such a scenario energy dissipation will be negligable.

As we know, here on Earth we have to use bearings, and in the demonstrations we know the energy of the nutation dissipates quite rapidly. (Once again, this tends to hide the essential role of the nutation dynamics.)

---

[LATER EDIT]
Some additional remarks.
As mentioned, the onset of a torque kicks in a nutation. Without any friction that nutation will persist.

However, presumably it is possible to shape the onset of the torque in such a way that very little energy is put into nutation motion. Perhaps a very gradual onset of the torque will do the trick. Or perhaps there is a way to pulse the torque initially, synchronized with the nutation frequency in such a way that you are also counteracting the nutation.

Conversely, when the starting situation is one of a torque sustaining a precession (and zero nutation), and you suddenly remove that torque then that also will kick in a nutation. This is specifically the scenario of your question.

Once again, presumably it is possible to mitigate the effect of nutation-kicking-in by very careful timing (either a precisely designed gradual decrease of the torque, or a phase of measured synchronized pulsing.)

Answer (score 1):

Simple - it will stop precessing, and it will continue to rotate about the axis, with the latter at the direction it was at when the torque stopped acting on the gyro.

Comment: In that case, where will the precession energy go i.e. the work done by that torque?

Comment: There isn't any. All of the rotational energy is encased in the rotation around the axis. The torques that cause precession are orthogonal to that axis and they do not affect that rotational energy - they just change the direction of the rotation axis that holds it. In other words, there is no inertia for precession.

Comment: There is an energy transfer by the torque initially as the gyroscope first rotates a little in the direction of torque only then it starts precessing. This is the principle behind gyrostabilizers often used for marine applications.

Comment: There are energy transfers in spinning up a gyro and in friction. However, there are no energy transfers in pure precession.